# How to get the first image and make it as a new div?

Tags: javascript, html, thumbnails

In my homepage in the post section there is this code:

```
<script>
function bp_thumbnail_resize(image_url,post_title)
{
  var show_default_thumbnail=true;
  if (show_default_thumbnail == true && image_url == "") image_url= default_thumbnail;
  image_tag='<img src="'+image_url.replace('/s72-c/','/')+'" class="postimg" alt="'+post_title+'"/>';
  if(image_url!="") return image_tag;
  else return "";
}
</script>
<script>
document.write(bp_thumbnail_resize(&quot;<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>&quot;,&quot;<data:post.title/>&quot;));
</script>
```

It creates a thumbnail of the image inside the post. But it loads the thumb AND the image - I've hidden with `.post img {display:none;}` - but the loading time is now 3x slower because it generates 3 sizes of the thumb + original hidden image. I want to remove the thumbs, but I still need to pick up the first image src, and creat a div to personalize it.

How can I do it? (The website is www.hitsebeats.info)

Comment: Just as an aside, that JS really needs to be formatted better, and `document.write` replaced with something like jQuery methods. Will make debugging in the future easier.

Comment: Isn't there any method using only JS I can pick up the first image and give it a new class so I can personalize in the home screen?